# Symmetric function and product of two functions

Tags: functions

**Question:** [amended referring to the comments below]

In reading up on a nice result among generative mechanisms for outcomes that are described by power law distributions, I came across [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0309659.pdf) paper, where the central claim is that given a function $f(x, y)$ that governs the link formation probability between two nodes, one can derive the conditions under which a scale-free network structure emerges.

The authors assert that $f(x,y)$ is a function that is symmetric with respect to its arguments and consider the case when $f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)$. Based on this, they conclude that $g(x) \equiv h(x)$? I am trying to trace the arguments to support this assertion.

**Attempt:**

I started by assuming that $g(x) \neq h(x)$ for any $x$. So, let $g(x) = \lambda h(x), \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, $f(x, y) = \lambda h(x)h(y)$ and $f(y, x) = \lambda h(y) h(x)$. This means that $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$ irrespective of $\lambda$, i.e., we are unable to conclude that the original assumption of unequal $g$ and $h$ is true unless $\lambda = 1$.

Any other approach to prove the question?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true at all! For example, the function $f(x,y)  \equiv 2$ is symmetric, obviously, and can also be written as $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$ where $g(x) \equiv 2$ and $h(x) \equiv 1$.

It is true that $g(x)h(y)  = g(y)h(x)$ for all $x,y$ by symmetry. Only if, we furthermore suppose there is some $X$ such that $g(X) = h(X) \neq 0$, then for all $Y$, $g(Y) = h(Y)$ by cancellation. However, this may not always happen, as the example above shows.

Comment: You are right! Actually, this appeared as a part of this paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0309659.pdf. In page 2, where the authors explicitly state - 'We start with the special case of f(x, y) = g(x)h(y)
where both the direct and inverse problems can be analytically
solved. Because of the symmetry of f(x, y) with
respect to its arguments one has g(x) ≡ h(x), so that
f(x, y) = g(x)g(y)'.

Comment: @buzaku Would be better if you added that context to the posted question. It follows from the answer above that $g,h$ differ at most by a multiplicative constant. If there is some additional scaling constraint/assumption (such that for example $g,h$ are probability density functions) then it would indeed follow that $g\equiv h$, though I don't know that's necessarily the case in the linked paper.

Comment: amended the question. I re-read the paper but cant trace $g$ and $h$ to be pdfs. I guess the key thing like you point out is that they differ at most by a multiplicative constant. I will work out if this makes any difference to the results in the paper.